# How can JRE be enough for Tomcat to handle JSP files? Why not JDK?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat6

Can someone clearly describe how JRE handles the JSP files which contain pure JAVA codes? I know that byte codes of JSP files are not placed in the WAR file. It consists of compiled CLASS files and plain JSP files.

It says in Tomcat's RUNNING.txt *"Apache Tomcat 6.0 requires the Java 2 Standard Edition Runtime Environment (JRE) version 5.0 or later."*

Please kill my pain.

Answer (score 25):

Tomcat bundles a copy of the Eclipse compiler, rather than using the JDK javac compiler. It's faster (or, at least, it used to be), has less restrictive licensing, and removes the dependency on the full JDK.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html

> The Eclipse JDT Java compiler is now
>   used to perform JSP java source code
>   compilation

This suggests that prior to Tomcat 5.5, the full JDK was required.

Comment: Where is it? Is it the `ecj*.jar` file in the `lib` directory?

Answer (score -5):

**Tomcat** is a web-container to get the JSP and Servlets run. 
**Tomcat implements** Sun's **Servlet and JSP specifications**. 
Tomcat can run the compiled Java class files. To accomplish that purpose only it needs JRE, 
nothing more than that.

Do you know? JSPs will also be converted into Servlet code...

**Tomcat** comprises of Servlet and JSP execution engines called **Catalina** (serves as a Servlet container) and **Jasper** (serves as a JSP container), which converts the JSP code to Servlet code and passes it to the Catalina container.

Comment: None of which answers the question. JSPs are compiled into `.java` source, which then needs to be further compiled into `.class` files. The JRE cannot do that, which was the gist of the question.